# java.lang.Void in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I am currently working with .Net 2.0 and have an interface whose generic type is used to define a method's return type. Something like

```
interface IExecutor<T> {
  T Execute() { ... }
}
```

My problem is that some classes that implement this interface do not really need to return anything.

In Java you can use java.lang.Void for this purpose, but after quite a bit of searching I found no equivalent in C#. More generically, I also did not find a good way around this problem. I tried to find how people would do this with delegates, but found nothing either - which makes me believe that the problem is that I suck at searching :)

So what's the best way to solve this? How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution, other than to throw away genericity and use different classes/interfaces for the `void` and non-`void` cases. That's what .NET itself does with the `Func` and `Action` types in 3.5. Coming from C++, this frequently annoys me, but I wasn't aware that Java had a way around it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to have to either just use Object and return null, create your own object to represent void, or just make a separate interface that returns void.

Here's an idea for the second one:

```
public class Void
{
    public static readonly Void Instance = null; // You don't even need this line
    private Void() {}
}
```

that way someone can't create an instance of the class. But you have something to represent it. I think this might be the most elegant way of doing what you want.

Also, you might want to make the class `sealed` as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought so too... I've been using object and had thought about creating my own Void, but both seemed so ugly I thought it better to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Object as the type , and return null.
That means you might need to write an adapter if you need to call a delecate who does in fact have a  `void` return type